# What does 『好き』が強い感がある

Tags: meaning

In the below I'm not quite sure how to understand the bold part. Before this he was flash backing and describing an event from a few days ago where his girlfriend 莉佳 was being very intimate (激しいスキンシップ　but nothing of that nature).

莉佳のことはもちろん大好きだけれど、その……ちょっと**その『好き』が強い感がある**

There's a few things I don't understand about what he says (and obviously the meaning).

- Why is 『好き』 in quotes? It doesn't seem like he is quoting anyone.
- 感がある - What's the difference between 感じがする and 感がある

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 好き is enclosed in brackets because the author knew this was a tricky expression that may not make sense to the readers instantly. English double-quotes (`""`) also has this function, too ([scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)).

好きが強い is not an idiomatic expression, and this is not intended to be interpreted in isolation. You have to make sense of it *from the context*. I expect some sort of explanation follows after such a tricky expression.

If I have to guess, possible interpretations include:

- My feeling is closer to "like" rather than "love"
- Her feeling is closer to "like" rather than "love"
- My "love" is so overwhelming

The difference between 感がある and 感じがする is small, but the former is relatively slangy, and tends to refer to  an even more vague feeling the speaker is somehow feeling.

Comment: From context and the following lines, I think it would be something more along the lines of your third option, but I am thinking he could be talking about her instead, although I am not sure. The following lines are: 何かをする前でこの有様では、した後はどうなってしまうんだろうか。行為の前からすでに俺は不安でいっぱいだった

Comment: @hockiefan52 Okay, then it's the third option, "My love toward her is becoming too strong (beyond control)". You may be interested in this question, too: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62983/5010