# で particle following い-adjective

Tags: sentence, particle-で, i-adjectives

A sentence from 「ぼっち・ざ・らじお！」episode 19, where the host 青山吉能さん thanks the audience for nominating their show in four categories for a radio show awards show.
She then says:

いろいろと後ろめたい**で**定評のあるアニラジがまさかまさかの展開でびっくりしました。

"I was surprised by the unexpected development of an Aniraj (anime radio) that has a reputation for being guilty of various things". (referring to the nominations)

後ろめたい is an い-adjective, so I would expect something like こと to come after in, similar to the familiar ことで有名 pattern "is famous for being X", this time with 定評 "has an established reputation for being X". So it's definitely the condition marker で. It would also make sense as a noun instead, 後ろめたさで. For what it's worth the autogenerated YT subtitles could've been wrong, but listening to the sentence a couple times and she 100% straight says 後ろめたいで. How could this be?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62983/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already pointed out, this sentence means the same as 後ろめたいことで定評のある although こと is dropped. I think this elimination happened because the writer treated 後ろめたい (or いろいろと後ろめたい) as a set phrase or a quote.